# Is using an external blogging platform and URL bad for SEO?

Tags: seo, search-engines, blog, blogger

I want to add a blog to my website to update the user on the new features.  The rest of the website is custom code and does not use any CMS.  For the blog, I want to use something like Blogger and put a 'Blog' link on my website to the Blogger website. Is this bad in terms of SEO?

Will search engines put my blogger higher than my main website? The blog will have more content than my main website.

Would I be better off creating a blog inside my domain (example.com/blog rather than example.blogspot.com)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are better off keeping the blog on your own domain for a vast amount of reasons but there is also no harm in using an external blog if it makes it easier for your business to manage and maintain. It is unlikely that your blog will rank above your website for the same terms (one would not expect your blog and website to be ranking for the same terms).

Even if you did use Blogger for example, you can still configure this to run on your own custom domain and [even in a sub directory of your own domain](http://matt-stannard.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/blogger-in-subdirectory-of-my-domain.html) (i.e `/blog`) by setting up the necessary DNS records.

Comment: How can you host a blog on Blogger under youdomain.com/blog with just DNS and without a reverse proxy? Also, I would expect my blog to rank for the same keywords as the website itself.

Comment: You might be able to make it `blog.example.com` without using a reverse proxy.  It would depend on whether blogger allows that or not.

Comment: Added link to answer which includes a way to host a Blogger blog in a sub directory on your domain. I have not tried this myself though but apparently it works.

Comment: That uses a reverse proxy (in that case implemented with PHP).

Comment: Why can't they use a reverse proxy (have I missed that)?

Comment: Your answer states that all they need to do is set up DNS records.   If you are suggesting using a reverse proxy, you should clarify your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Blogger will allow you to use blog.example.com - and I have done this successfully.

It does not allow example.com/blog

If you use Blogger, then your content is hosted on blogger's servers.   You should take regular backups  (using Google Takeout) in case anything goes wrong - but overall your security risks seem to be less on Blogger than on Wordpress which is more of a target due to the sheer size of the user-base, and the propensity of 3rd party plugins to not be kept up do date.

As to whether this is good or bad for SEO - the rules are always changing.   Making sure your blog is regularly updated with unique, useful content which has appropriate links to your main website will probably make more SEO difference than any detailed of where your content is hosted.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make a subdomain of my site's domain for the blog. Something like: www.example.com (your website) and blog.example.com (for the blog). Or www.example.com/blog.

Using something as simple as WordPress for the blog, setting it up on my website, using the same domain.